# Error in -data$group : invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I would like to use `frame` with `ggplotly` to have an animated histogram. When I run the following code it returns an error:

```r
# Reproducible data
set.seed(7)
df = data.frame(
  day = factor(rep(1:7, each = 100)),
  value = runif(700, 0, 1)
)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = value, frame = day)) +
  geom_histogram()
ggplotly(p)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Error in -data$group: invalid argument to unary operator
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I found this [issue](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/149), but this is with regard to using `gganimate` with `geom_bar`. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this error to create an animated histogram with `ggplotly`?

Comment: May I know what does the argument `frame = day` indicate?
I am not very familiar with ggplot2 aesthetics, but if I define p as `p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = value)) +  geom_histogram()`, the code returns no error.

Comment: Hi @TheN, With frame you can make the ggplot in ggplotly animated with a slider based on a variable it will show different plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by using `position = "identity"` which will create an animated histogram in `ggplotly` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = value, frame = day)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "identity")
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>